# How to show notification from Android wear watchface

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to show a notification from my Watch face, as I want to show additional information when the user first opens the watchface.

This is similar to the GMT watch face that is installed with the LG G Watch R, that asks the user to swipe left to select the timezone.

This code does not seem to work for me:

```
  Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Content");

        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
                .notify(1, builder.build());
```

This was copied from one of Android wear's examples (was not used in a watchface example, just a regular wear app)

Comment: Have you tried NotificationCompat? https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Anything in logcat?

Comment: Nothing in Logcat to identify any problem. Just the notification is not shown.
@dazza5000, please note that I want the notification to be shown only on the watch, so there should not be any need to use the compat library that is intended for older Android versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely missing the icon, you need to specify the icon for Android to show your notification. Try specifying everything that the example from the docs mentions:

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
         .setContentText(subject)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
         .build();
```

Comment: Yeah, the icon did it!